# How to find out the name and path of a running gui application on linux?

Tags: filenames

I am interested to learn more about my system. Started for example a GUI application "Printing". A shiny nice name in the title.

There is no file "printing" in /usr/bin.

Is there some trick to show the real name of the application in the filesystem instead of "printing", for example "printgui"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually GUI applications are started through "launchers", i.e. [.desktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) files. You are seeing "Printing" in your menus instead of the real name because that is the "generic name" of the application (details in the link I posted). Depending on what DE you are using you might be able to right click on the menu entry and select `Edit` or `Properties` which would allow you to see the executable path and sometimes the real name for that app. That's not possible in a DE like Gnome 3 so here is a solution that should work regardless of your DE.

`.desktop` files are located in `/usr/share/applications` so simply `grep`-ing for ***GenericName=Printing*** should list at least one launcher containing that string.

E.g. I don't have "Printing" on my system but I have "Text Editor". I want to know the real name of the application/executable so I run:

```
grep "GenericName=Text Editor" /usr/share/applications/*
```

which outputs:

```
/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop:GenericName=Text Editor
```

So the "launcher" for "Text Editor" is `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop`. Now, in order to know the real name and executable for "Text Editor" I have to grep the value of two keys: `Name` and `Exec`:

```
grep -E '(^Name=|^Exec=)' /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop
```

which outputs:

```
Name=gedit
Exec=gedit %U
```

For the full path of the executable, it's only a matter or running:

```
which gedit
```

and that returns:

```
/usr/bin/gedit
```

Answer (score 3):

I transposed answer above into the script *execCmdGnome3.sh* shown below. I use this utility to find out how to call applications out of terminal whose gnome shell name I know.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Name: execCmdGnome3.sh
# Usage e.g.: sudo execCmdGnome3.sh "Document Viewer" 
# Output: Found Launcher: "evince.desktop"
#         Name=Document Viewer
#         Exec=evince %U

launcher=`grep "$1" /usr/share/applications/* | sed s/.*applications.// | sed s/:.*// | uniq`
echo "Found Launcher: \"$launcher\""
grep -E '(^Name=|^Exec=)' "/usr/share/applications/$launcher"
```